# InstallShield upgrade from 32bit exe to 64 bit exe failed

Tags: 32bit-64bit, installshield, installscript

I am trying to upgrade my project.  My earlier project had the 32 bit exe and now it is using 64 bit exe.

While upgrading it ts giving following error:

```
WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 
'C:\Program Files (x86)\SHAKESPEARE_INC\Othello\' 
folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's 
iSwapAttrib member = 0).
```

I searched and found [this](http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=20624) link, but could not find the solution for the problem.

Does anyone know any possible solution for this?

Comment: Is your problem regarding deploying to 64 bit hive or file system?

Comment: Because in that case, you should set 64 bit component field to Yes for those components.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the option 64 bit component to **true** in your component that deploys the exe.